# Error when updating the node

Tags: node, updates

I'm trying to update my node to the latest version but I'm stuck with the following error message on my Ubuntu 18.04 box:

```
File "none", line 1:
Error: Files vendors/ocplib-resto/lib_resto-cohttp/resto_cohttp.cmxa
and /home/test/tezos/_opam/lib/cohttp-lwt-unix/cohttp_lwt_unix.cmxa
make inconsistent assumptions over implementation Cohttp_lwt_unix__Client
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any idea where I missed something?

Answer (score 9):

Try the following in the tezos folder:

Update your packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Make sure to have the right version of the code and clean everything:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/mainnet
git clean -dxf
```

Update opam packages:

```
opam update
opam upgrade
```

Build everything again:

```
eval $(opam env)
make build-deps
eval $(opam env)
make
```